# Is specifying list items type important in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I recently started learning Flutter and hence Dart.
Unlike Python, everyone seems to be specifying the datatype of the list items whenever they create a list in Dart. I don't really want to, so is it really important to do so, or is it just one of those norms?

```
List<String> names = [
  "Faisal",
  "Saifi"
];
```

It still works without doing it so let me know should I or should I not. As there isn't really this question anywhere asked here (Or I didn't come across it).

Comment: Specifying the type is important *if* the type cannot be inferred.  In your example, `var names = ["Faisal", "Saifi"];` is perfectly fine and would be no different.  If, however, you did `var names = [];`, then `names` would be of type `List<dynamic>` instead of `List<String>`.  In that case, you should be explicit: `var names = <String>[];`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to specify the type of list when you are defining it, but in a complex app in order to avoid facing assigning value error, it is good to define list with type.
for example you supposed to getting List of string from api bit some you are getting list of int if you define you list like `List`, you never notice that and you will get error some where else in you complex app, but if you define your list like `List<String>` you will get exception on that and you now why that is happening.

Comment: When type inference works, it's great.  But sometimes, it needs a bit of help. So we help it.  Luckily, the IDE can show the inferences pretty easily with a hover or two.